# Swift replace substring regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xcode, swift

I am attempting to use regular expression to replace all occurrences of UK car registrations within a string.

The following swift code works perfectly for a when the string matches the regex exactly as below.

```
var myString = "DD11 AAA"
var stringlength = countElements(myString) 
var ierror: NSError?
var regex:NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &ierror)!
var modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, stringlength), withTemplate: "XX")
print(modString)
```

The result is `XX`

However, the following does not work and the string is not modifed

```
var myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB"
var stringlength = countElements(myString) 
var ierror: NSError?
var regex:NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &ierror)!
var modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, stringlength), withTemplate: "XX")
print(modString)
```

The result is `my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB`

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

The `^` means *start of string* and `$` means *end of string* (or line, depending on the options). That's why your first example works: in the first test string, the start of the string is really followed by your pattern and ends with it.

In the second test string, the pattern is found in the middle of the string, thus the `^...` can't apply. If you would just remove the `^`, the `$` would apply on the second occurrence of the registration number and the output would be `my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - XX`.

```
let myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, myString.count)
let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "XX")
print(modString)
// Output: "my car reg 1 - XX  my car reg 2 - XX"
```

Comment: the option that DarkDust mention is `AnchorsMatchLines`

Comment: for some reason NSRegularExpression doesn't seem to be working in swift 3. How would you go about correcting this?

Answer (score 33):

Let's use a class extension to wrap this up in Swift 3 syntax:

```
extension String {
    mutating func removingRegexMatches(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)
            self = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch { return }
    }
}

var phoneNumber = "+1 07777777777"
phoneNumber.removingRegexMatches(pattern: "\\+\\d{1,4} (0)?")
```

Results in `7777777777` (thus removing country code from phone number)

Comment: use of NSMakeRange generates `warning: Legacy Constructor Violation: Swift constructors are preferred over legacy convenience functions. (legacy_constructor)` in swiftlint

Comment: @ablarg you can fix that by replacing the line with: `let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count)`

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4.2 Updated

```
let myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB"
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}", options: .caseInsensitive) {
    let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length:  myString.count), withTemplate: "XX")
    print(modString)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Update for Swift 2.1:

```
var myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB"
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}", options: .CaseInsensitive) {
    let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, myString.characters.count), withTemplate: "XX")
    print(modString)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Warning**

Do not use `NSRange(location: 0, length:  myString.count)` as all examples above quoted.

Use `NSRange(myString.startIndex..., in: myString)` instead!

`.count` will count newline characters like `\r\n` as one character - this may result in a shortened, thus invalid, NSRange that does not match the whole string.

(.length should work)

Answer (score 6):

Simple extension:

```
extension String {

    func replacingRegex(
        matching pattern: String,
        findingOptions: NSRegularExpression.Options = .caseInsensitive,
        replacingOptions: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [],
        with template: String
    ) throws -> String {

        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: findingOptions)
        let range = NSRange(startIndex..., in: self)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: replacingOptions, range: range, withTemplate: template)
    }
 }
```

#### ✅ Advantages to other answers

- Exposed throwing `error` to the caller
- Exposed finding options to the caller with default for the ease of use
- Exposed replacing options to the caller with default for the ease of use
- Fixed the `range` **BUG**  in the original answer

Answer (score 4):

With `pattern: "^ ... $"` you have specified that the pattern is anchored
to the start and end of the string, in other words, the *entire* string
must match the pattern. Just remove `^`  and `$` from the pattern
and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

A notice to all answers that uses `.count` in their answers:

This will cause problems in cases that the operating target range has surrogate-paired characters.

Please fix your answers by using `.utf16.count` instead.

Here's Ryan Brodie 's answer with this fix. It works with Swift 5.5.

```swift
private extension String {
    mutating func regReplace(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchorsMatchLines])
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
            self = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch { return }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** If considering @coyer 's concerns:

```swift
private extension String {
    mutating func regReplace(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchorsMatchLines])
            let range = NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)
            self = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch { return }
    }
}
```

---

**Also:** to @Martin R' :
It is okay to use ^ and $ in Regex as long as you have enabled the ".anchorsMatchLines" in the Regex options. I already applied this option in the codeblocks above.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.7 update**

```swift
let myString = "my car reg 1 - DD11 AAA  my car reg 2 - AA22 BBB"
let regex = #/([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}/#
let modString = myString.replacing(regex.ignoresCase(), with: "XX")

print(modString)
// Output: "my car reg 1 - XX  my car reg 2 - XX"
```