# Swift replace string found in HTML tag

Tags: html, ios, swift

I get a HTML string from my API that i display in a UIWebView in my app.

This HTML can contain images that are protected by authentication, so i add replace the URL with an username:password@url:

```
generatedHtml = generatedHtml.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(urlWithoutAuthentication, withString: authenticatedUrl)
```

This does stringReplace on the entire HTML, how can i limit this to only  tags?

Comment: Give example, and the result you want

Comment: check if this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503449/swift-replace-substring-regex