# Regex return only digits up to a new line character

Tags: regex, swift

i have this text in which i need to extract only the digits on the first line

`+1-415-655-0001 US TOLL
 Access code: 197 703 792`

the regex i have just extracts all digits
`/d+`

```
var noteStr = "1-415-655-0001 US TOLL\n\nAccess code: 197 703 792"

findCodeInWord()

func findCodeInWord() -> String?
{
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+", options: [])

    var items = [String]()
    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(noteStr, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, noteStr.characters.count)) { result, flag, stop in
        guard let match = result else {
            // result is nil
            return
        }

        let range = match.rangeAtIndex(0)
        var matchStr = (noteStr as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
        print(matchStr)
    }
    return items.joinWithSeparator("")

}
```

but this returns all the digits. I only want it to return 14156550001

Comment: Use `[^0-9]+` as your regex and the replacement string as empty. I don't know Swift but apparently there's a function for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503449/swift-replace-substring-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract these numbers with a single regex based on a `\G` operator and capturing the digits into Group 1:

```
\G(?:[^\d\n\r]*(\d+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR8qN9/1), it will only capture into Group 1 digit sequences (1 or more, with `(\d+)`) that are on the first line due to `\G` operator that matches at the beginning of the string and then at the end of each successful match and the `[^\d\n\r]*` character class matching 0+ characters other than digit, LF or CR.

Thus, when it starts matching, `1` is found and captured, then `-` is matched with `[^\d\n\r]*`, then `415` is matched and captured, etc. When `\n` is encountered, no more match is found, the `\G` anchor fails and thus, the whole regex search stops at the first line.

Swift:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\G(?:[^\\d\n\r]*(\\d+))", options: [])
...
let range = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
```

Comment: Thanks wiktor! This was exactly what i was looking for. +1 for explaining it as well. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have this text in which i need to extract only the digits on the first line"*

While regex is very useful at times, for a simple task as extracting only number characters from a given string, Swifts native [*pattern matching*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html) is a useful tool; appropriate here as the `UnicodeScalar` representation of numbers `0` through `9` is in sequence:

```
var noteStr = "1-415-655-0001 US TOLL\n\nAccess code: 197 703 792"

/* since we're using native pattern matching, let's use a native method
   also when extracting the first row (even if this is somewhat simpler
   if using Foundation bridged NSString methods)                            */
if let firstRowChars = noteStr.characters.split("\n").first,
    case let firstRow = String(firstRowChars) {

    // pattern matching for number characters
    let pattern = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
    let numbers = firstRow.unicodeScalars
        .filter { pattern ~= $0 }
        .reduce("") { String($0) + String($1) }

    print(numbers) // 14156550001

    /* Alternatively use .reduce with an inline if clause directly:
    let numbers = firstRow.unicodeScalars
        .reduce("") { pattern ~= $1 ? String($0) + String($1) : String($0)} */
}
```