# Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

How to convert values of type `'[String : AnyObject]?'`to expected argument type `'[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'`?

```
open class func drawText(context: CGContext, text: String, point: CGPoint, 
align: NSTextAlignment, attributes: [String : AnyObject]?)
{
    var point = point

    if align == .center
    {
        point.x -= text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width / 2.0
    }
    else if align == .right
    {
        point.x -= text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width
    }

    NSUIGraphicsPushContext(context)

    (text as NSString).draw(at: point, withAttributes: attributes)

    NSUIGraphicsPopContext()
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a new feature of Swift 4. All the Cocoa methods that take string identifiers and/or dictionary keys now have their own types for the keys. The reason for this is to add a bit of type safety—in the old regime, it was possible to accidentally pass a `String` constant by mistake that was meant to be used with some other API, but now in Swift 4, this will result in a compilation error.

Change your method signature to:

```
open class func drawText(context: CGContext, text: String, point: CGPoint,
    align: NSTextAlignment, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?)
```

**EDIT:** Updated for Swift 4.2! `NSAttributedStringKey` has been renamed to `NSAttributedString.Key`.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Your `atrribute` argument is incorrect in the `drawText` function.

Change

```
open class func drawText(context: CGContext, text: String, point: CGPoint, align: NSTextAlignment, attributes: [String : AnyObject]?)
```

to

```
open class func drawText(context: CGContext, text: String, point: CGPoint, align: NSTextAlignment, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the Charts module. I ran into the same problem.

Changing the method argument fixes the error in that method, but pushes the problem up to all the callers of that method, which now have the same issue.

Is there a quick fix that doesn't involve changing the whole call stack?

Comment: Answers are not supposed to be used for asking questions. You should consider making a comment or asking a new question and refer to this one from there.