# Extract Integers, Decimals, and Fractional Numbers from sentence of a string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

How to extract the array of string with Integers, Decimals, and Fractions from a sentence?
Please find below input and output in iOS Swift.

Input :  array of String["width 32.3", "Length 61 1/4", "height 23 4/5", "measure 5.23"]

Output : ["32.3", "61 1/4", "23 4/5", "5.23"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this for supporting regex matches for string:

```
extension String {
    mutating func stringByRemovingRegexMatches(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
            let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
            self = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var str = ["width 32.3", "Length 61 1/4", "height 23 4/5", "measure 5.23"]
var vreturn:[String]=[]

for var s in str {
    s.stringByRemovingRegexMatches(pattern:"[a-zA-Z]", replaceWith: "")
    vreturn.append(s)
}

print( vreturn)
```

Source : [Swift replace substring regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503449/swift-replace-substring-regex)

Comment: the string will be any string, it's a dynamic test input, not only width, length, any string. For your case, if it is static data, your extraction is correct. for dynamic data, how to extract the numbers or fractions or digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my time. now it's perfectly working.

Comment: Consider that each extracted string starts with a (white)space character.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with Regular Expression

```
let array = ["width 32.3", "Length 61 1/4", "height 23 4/5", "measure 5.23"]
let pattern = "\\d+[\\s.][\\d/]+"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
var result = [String]()

for item in array {
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: item, range: NSRange(location:0, length: item.characters.count)) {
        result.append((item as NSString).substring(with: match.range))
    }
}

print(result)
```

The pattern searches for

- one or more digits
- followed by a whitespace character or dot
- followed by one or more digits or slashes

Comment: Thank you, this also works perfectly with exact output that what I need.