# replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "") Not Working On TextField.text

Tags: ios, swift

I get a input from uitextfield box. i can replace quotes("'") to empty(""). using

```
textfield.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "")
```

is not working

```
textfield.text = "name's"
let trim = textfield.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "")
```

expected OUTPUT:

> names

actual OUTPUT:

> name's

Comment: `textfield.text = "name's" let trim = textfield.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: "")` try that

Comment: Post the _actual_ code/input... the snippet you have posted in your question already produces your expected output.

Comment: Where do you have the `replacingOccurrences` code?

Comment: My guess: The text field does not contain an apostrophe (`'`) but a single left quotation mark (`‘`)

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503676/4757272 this regex to clean from all wierd characters.

Comment: As other people said, the first quote may actually be one of those _pesky_ smart quotes, rather than a straight quote. And with out more code, I’m thinking maybe you aren’t replacing the textfield’s text, or printing the right value (we need a bit more context). Make sure you do a `print(trim)` or if you’re trying to replace the textfield, `textfield.text=trim`

Comment: thanks. i can get the solution it contain smartquotes.smartquotes set to No its working.  Textfield.smartQuotesType = .no

Answer (score 0):

`text.replacingOccurrences` can be used with regular expressions so using the group ['`´] could work here (I am not aware of any meta character for this). As @Rob mentioned in the comments it might be worth expanding the pattern further like [‘’'`´] or [‘’‛'′´`❛❜] or use "\p{Quotation_Mark}"

```
let trim = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "['`´]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

It doesn't replace è or é which is good I suppose

```
let text = "name's are Josè and André, strings are `abc` and ´def´"
let trim = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "['`´]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

print(trim)
```

yields

> names are Josè and André, strings are abc and def

Comment: Maybe `[‘’'\`´]` or `[‘’‛'′´\`❛❜]`

Comment: Or, if you’re willing to throw double quotes under the bus, `text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\p{Quotation_Mark}"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)`.