# Replace occurrences of either comma or dot

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
let kmInput: Int = (addKmInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "") as NSString).integerValue
```

**Can I additionally replace occurrences of commas?** Or is the only way to solve it this way:

```
let kmInput: Int = (addKmInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
```

Comment: You could use a regex expression to represent the things you want to replace, in your case I think "[.,]", you can look at this question to see how to replace with regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503449/swift-replace-substring-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use `replacingOccurrences` that supports regular expressions, in this case `[,.]`

```
let result = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "[.,]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

the full code would then be

```
let kmInput = Int(addKmInput.text!
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "[.,]", 
                          with: "", 
                          options: .regularExpression))
```

Comment: why not just a regular filter operation?`.filter { $0 != "," && $0 != "." }` or even better if OP just want to allow numbers in that field `filter { $0.isWholeNumber }`