# Normalizing Phone Number in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is to make live input formatting, for example if user enter +381 65 1234 123 to show 0651234123

I managed to create func like this

```
func normalizeSerbianPhoneNumber(_ mobileNumber: String) -> String {

    let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+0123456789")
    let trimmedNumber = mobileNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    var strippedNumber = trimmedNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: allowedCharacterSet.inverted)

    // Remove all spaces from the number
    strippedNumber = strippedNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    // Remove leading country code or zeros
    if strippedNumber.hasPrefix("+381") {
        strippedNumber.removeFirst(4)
    } else if strippedNumber.hasPrefix("381") {
        strippedNumber.removeFirst(3)
    } else if strippedNumber.hasPrefix("0") {
        strippedNumber.removeFirst()
    }

    // Validate and format the number
    // Serbian mobile numbers typically start with '06' followed by 7-8 digits
    if (strippedNumber.count == 8 || strippedNumber.count == 9) && strippedNumber.hasPrefix("6") {
        return strippedNumber
    } else {
        return "The number you enter is invalid."
    }
}
```

And that works, but for example, when I copy +381 65 1234 123 inside that TextField, it shows that for half second and then change to 0651234123, how can I immediately format that without showing copied number.

this is my view

```
struct PhoneNumber: View {
    var title: String
    @Binding var phoneNumber: String
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    var action: () -> ()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Text(title)
                .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuRegular, size: 12))
            HStack{
                CountrySelectButton(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 290) {
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
                
                GrayTextField(placeholder: "000 000 0000", text: $phoneNumber)
                    .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                    .onChange(of: phoneNumber) { newValue in
                        let result = normalizeSerbianPhoneNumber(newValue)
                        if result != "The number you enter is invalid." {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                phoneNumber = result
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SelectCountrySheet()
                .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use regular expression replacements? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503449/swift-replace-substring-regex

Comment: Long time without working with swift but, why do you need the DispatchQueue.main.async? I think you can try to update the change directly as phoneNumber = result; this may be the cause of the latency. Because otherwise it should be instantaneous. Unless it does not allow you because you are changing the field that just fired a change event. I don't remember this kinds of details.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (cannot see old value on paste), but try to use `.onReceive(Just(phoneNumber)) { newValue in` - onReceive happens before onChange

Comment: Hi @DanielCruz, thanks, this worked!